# Отображение дополнительной информации в нижней части окна

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть окно, в котором есть кнопка, при нажатии на нее окно должно увеличиваться и выводить в нижней части дополнительную информацию, например, сообщение об ошибке.И желательно, чтобы окно было масштабируемым. Как лучше это можно сделать?
Примерно так это может выглядеть:

[image: ]]

Comment: Ох жалко мне ваших пользователей... Окна, которые меняют размер - зачастую подбешивают) Я считаю, что окно должно быть статичным и только по желанию пользователя менять размер, а вот внутри окна, вы можете делать уже всякие всплывающие уведомления и тому подобное.

Comment: Делайте окну `SizeToContent = Height`, в нижней строке грида помещаете нужный элемент и скрываете его, а при необходимости делаете его видимым. А вообще, конечно, я согласен с предыдущим комментарием

Comment: @Андрей NOP, спасибо, так и сделал.